# Checking for a radio button's state (javascript/canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I have is a canvas, and an input elsewhere on the HTML page that lets you type stuff in and it appears on the canvas. There are multiple background images, and there is one in particular that is dark. No biggie, just make it so when the radio button is clicked, it will update the colours to be white instead. Problem is, if you add new content, the text colour changes back to black, making it hard to see again. Is there any way to get the javascript to check which radio button is clicked instead of relying on "onClick"?

```
function text(imgURL){
    var asdf = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=asdf.getContext("2d");
    asdf.width = asdf.width;
    var val = input.value;
    if(imgURL === "dark.png"){
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    }else if(imgURL === "dark2.png"){
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    }else if(imgURL === "dark3.png"){
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    }else{
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";  
    }
    ctx.font = "bold 22px sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "right";
    ctx.fillText(val, 349, 47);
}
```

Comment: show some code pleeeeease :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(document.getElementById('radio_id').checked) {
  //this is checked
}
```

And so on..

Comment: Thanks! It worked! This was a real help! (I can't accept the answer yet, because it won't let me, but I will in a moment)

Answer (score 5):

```
if(document.getElementById('what_ever_the_id_is').checked == true)
//your code
```

Similarly, you can use it for checkboxes also.